# Angular 4 - Datatables is called before data population

Tags: angular, datatables

I'm fetching data from backend and binds in to the view as table rows, then i'm calling datatable funtion on the table, but the function is called before the view shows the rows.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vendors',
  templateUrl: './vendors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vendors.component.css']
})
export class VendorsComponent implements OnInit {

  vendors: any;
  constructor(private http:  HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get('backendgetLINK').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      this.vendors = data['vendors'];
        $("#vendors-datatable").DataTable({});

      console.log(this.vendors);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vendors',
  templateUrl: './vendors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vendors.component.css']
})
export class VendorsComponent implements OnInit {

  vendors: any;
  dataRetrieved:any;
  constructor(private http:  HttpClient) { 
this.dataRetrieved=false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get('backendLINK').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      this.vendors = data['vendors'];
      this.dataRetrieved=true;
        // $("#vendors-datatable").DataTable({});

      console.log(this.vendors);
    });
  }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if (this.dataRetrieved) {
   $("#vendors-datatable").DataTable({});
  }
}

}
```

is this proper one ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lifecycle hook `ngAfterViewInit` which will be called after the components view and its child views has been initialized.

try this

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    $("#vendors-datatable").DataTable({});
}
```

Comment: getting data from http will take time, may be `.http.get()` have some callback like this `.http.get().then()` . please check the docs i am not sure